# find inputs in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In the below table which is generated dynamically, I want to traverse and find html controls (input,select,textarea) using JavaScript DOM. I don't want span and div values.

Can anyone give an idea on how to traverse?

```
 <html>
     <head>Html</head>
         <body>
            <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div id="one"></div>
                  </td>
                   <td>
                      <input type="text" name="textbox" id="txtid" value=10"/>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <select id="cuskstatus"  name="cuskstatus" class="selectStyleBorder">
                                <option selected value="LOCAL">Local</option>
                                <option value="GLOBAL">Global</option>
                       </select>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td>
                        <textarea id="tareaid" name="" value="10"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="span1">value</span>
                    </td>
              </tr>
           </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If the items order is not important you can use `document.getElementByTagName`.

Comment: Can you use jQuery or are you limited to plain JavaScript ?

Comment: @jnpcl javascript much better but jquery ok no problem

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this

```
var desired_tag_names = new Array('select', 'input', 'textarea');

function getElements(e) {
   var elements = new Array();
   for (i=0; i<e.length; i++) {
      var el = document.getElementsByTagName(e[i]);
      for (j=0; j<el.length; j++) {
         elements.push(el[j]);
      }
   }
   return elements;
}

var all_the_desired_elements = getElements(desired_tag_names);
```

Comment: @teneff thanks but requirement is if we take a row we must get all html controls and then only switch over to next row...let me know if u have any doubts...

Comment: @teneff please explain these getElements(document.getElementById('row199'), desired_tag_names); i am new to js...

Comment: @teneff one more thing table is generated dynamically so i dont know the id document.getElementById('row199') as you mentioned row199

Comment: the first parameter passed to the function is a refference of the element with id="row199"

Answer (score 1):

In plain JavaScript, just use [`form.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements).

Assuming that you've a `<form id="formid">`:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById("formid").elements;
// ...
```

Or if you want to traverse all forms of the document on a per-form basis, just use [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.forms) to get all forms first.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
    var form = document.forms[i];
    var inputs = form.elements;
    // ...
}
```

---

If you're already using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), or are open to, use [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector.

```
var $inputs = $(':input');
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying jQuery makes this problem trivial:

```
$('input','select','textarea')
```

This will return a jQuery collection of all input, select and textarea elements.

Comment: It's not a good solution to include whole library just to collect few elements on the page :)

Comment: Good is subjective. From a pragmatic perspective of getting things done quickly with the right tools, it's a great solution.

Comment: Using jQuery for this is great if you already use jQuery in your project. Including jQuery just to do this is like hunting rabbits with nuclear weapons.

Comment: I wasn't going to down-vote this, but your comment made me do it, sorry. Suggesting that jQuery is the "right tool" to do a simple DOM-selection because the developer can't be arsed to do his job correctly is simply not ok in my book. You do realise that the end user will suffer a performance penalty for that lazy decision on every single page load, right?

Comment: @Adrian: Not too much of a penalty, if they already have jQuery cached from the CDN. :)

Comment: @jnpcl Yes, too much, I think. Remember that the downloading is not the only cost that applies. The JS has to be parsed and run too. And depending on how expire headers are set up, it might invoke an unnecessary http round trip. And apart from performance penalties, teaching javascript beginners to throw jQuery at every single problem won't make them better programmers, and it won't make the web a better platform.